# Tesseract-OCR in VS2012 errors

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tesseract

I use tesseract-ocr in Visual Studio 2012 without any problems. I installed tesseract to my friend's computer. But it gave errors. Everything is the same as mine(VS2012 configuration, tesseract-OCR installation, etc.)

Error List in baseapi.h:

```
Error 1 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'OcrEngineMode'
Error 2 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'OcrEngineMode'
Error 3 error C2535: 'int tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(const char ,const char )' : member function already defined or declared 
Error 4 error C2535: 'int tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(const char ,const char )' : member function already defined or declared 
Error 5 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PageSegMode'
Error 6 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'GetPageSegMode'
Error 7 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error 9 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PageIteratorLevel'
Error 10 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PageSegMode'
Error 11 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'const' 
Error 12 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error 13 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'last_oem_requested_'
Error 14 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error 15 error C3867: 'tesseract::TessBaseAPI::oem': function call missing argument list; use '&tesseract::TessBaseAPI::oem' to create a pointer to member 
Error 16 error C2660: 'tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init' : function does not take 8 arguments
Error 17 error C2065: 'OEM_DEFAULT' : undeclared identifier
Error 18 error C2065: 'last_oem_requested_' : undeclared identifier
```